# Principles For Use of "The"

Tags: definite-article

I'm struggling to understand when exactly I should use "the" and when I should not.

It would be great if provide some simple principle or refer me to a textbook.

Comment: The use of articles is one of the toughest things in the English language. I'm afraid it would be impossible to answer such a wide-ranging question in a single post. Quirk et al's book "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" dedicates 30 pages to article usage..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can find a book totally dedicated to *articles*, but I'll list you the uses explained by *Tim Falla* & *Paul A. Davies* from *Solutions Upper — Intermediate Student's Book.*

> ***the***
>   We use the definite article *the*
>
> - when it's clear what we are talking about. This can be
>     **a** because we've already mentioned it
>               » *I've got a cat and a dog. The cat is called Freddy.*
>     **b** because there is only one of something
>               » *What time will the sun set this evening?*
>     **c** because it's clear from the situation
>               » *Let's go to the beach.* (The beach that's near here.)
> - with most nationality words.
>               » *The Italians have a reputation for being friendly.*
> - with the names of rivers, mountains ranges, deserts and seas.
>               » *The Nile, The Himalayas, The Sahara Desert, The Baltic.*
> - with a few countries and most groups of islands.
>               » *The United Kingdom, The United States, The Netherlands, The Czech 
>     Republic,              The Channel Islands.*
> - in various set phrases, for example:
>               »  *go to the theatre/cinema, listen to the radio/the news, play the violin/the piano.*
> - with an adjective to refer to everybody who has that characteristic.
>               » *the poor/the rich.*